# On becomeFirstResponder Show Placeholder

Tags: text, uitextfield, placeholder

Hi when I open up my textfield (becomeFirstResponder) it shows my text as text. How can I take the users input for that textfield (14.25) and make it a .placholder text. For example if the user puts in 14.25 in the text field when they get out and look out at the textfield it should be black like text, but when they click on the textfield again to edit it the current text (14.25) changes from .text to .placholder. Does that make sense? If it does not please let me know.

I dont really know what to do but I made a shot at it and nothing happened haha.

```
billAmountTextField.text = billAmountTextField.placeholder;
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand, but are you trying to replace the placeholder by the text, at the time you start editing? Of so, your line is in the wrong way. Try this:

```
billAmountTextField.placeholder = billAmountTextField.text;
```

Moreover, you need to clear out the text itself, if you want the placehold to show up.

```
billAmountTextField.text = @"";
```

Makes sense?